# Flutter graphql query, variables will not update, not sending the latest query

Tags: flutter, graphql, mobile-development

I have the following variables set. registerUser is the graphQL api call. I want $name, $password,$premium and $email to be dynamic variables which is determined when a button is pressed (Sign up). This code is all in a stateful widget.

```
    String name;
    String password = "";
    bool premium = false;
    String email = "dasa";
    String registerUser = '''
    mutation {
      addUserManual(name:"$name",password:"$password",premium:$premium,email:"$email"){
      userid
      }
    }
'''
```

Then I define a mutation per graphql_flutter plugin like this. In runmutation({.. the mutation sent to the server is that of the initial defined variables above, it does not send the most recent query. Does anyone know how update the vvalue from the fields and then insert this into the query?.

```
child: Mutation(options: MutationOptions(
                  documentNode: gql(registerUser),
                  update: (Cache cache, QueryResult result) {
                    return cache;
                  },
                  // or do something with the result.data on completion
                  onCompleted: (dynamic resultData) {
                    print(resultData);
                  },
                ), builder: (RunMutation runMutation, QueryResult result){
                  return RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 5,
                    onPressed: () {
                      //FIX LATER
                      print(result.data);
                      runMutation({'name':"hi",'password':"test",'premium':false,'email':"blabla"});
                    },
                    child: Text('SIGN UP'),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  );
                })
```

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that you're conflating dart variables with GraphQL variables. GraphQL is it's own language, and `graphql-flutter` can't pass variables on to GraphQL unless they are defined as parameters to the mutation, like so:

```dart
String registerUser = r'''
  mutation RegisterUser($name: String!, email: String!, $password: String!, $premium: Boolean = false){
    addUserManual(name: $name, password: $password, premium: $premium, email: $email){
      userid
    }
  }
''';
```

This parameterizes the mutation with [input variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables), as well as escapes the string with an `r` tag to prevent interpolation. Your original code run in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) yields

```
mutation {
  addUserManual(name:"null",password:"",premium:false,email:"dasa"){
    userid
  }
}
```

Which is a static `mutation` with the variables hardcoded in.